# Dynamics CRM 2011 - Hiding Out of Box Reports

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

How do you hide an Out of the Box report without deleting it?

It's possible to flip the flag in the database to unmanaged to delete an Out of the Box report, however we would like to retain them for potential future use. Is there a way to hide it from the available reports?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to edit the report as a System Administrator and under the Actions menu - choose Revert to Personal Report - then it would only be available to the admin user. If you want to use it again, you can reverse this by choosing the option Make Available to the Entire Organization.

Answer (score 3):

There is an option in the report settings (Customizations and/or Solutions)called "Display In".  This determines whether you see the report in the reports area and in forms for related record types.  Clear the e.g. Reports Area, save, publish and refresh your reports list.  The OOB report will no longer be there.